# Crypto-JS always return new hash

Tags: javascript, angular, cryptojs

I want to use [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) on my angular 8 application .
this is my example code :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable()
export class HprotoService {

  public enc(msg: string): string {
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, '1234').toString();
  }

  public dec(encMsg: string): string {
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encMsg, '1234').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

and my component :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HprotoService} from './hproto.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  private hproto: HprotoService;

  constructor(hproto: HprotoService) {
    this.hproto = hproto;
  }

  public encrypt() {
    console.log(this.hproto.enc('Hello dear !!!'));
  }
}
```

My problem is Crypto-JS always return different hash on this example !

> U2FsdGVkX19E9JKokPiRUZlrWsykZqAIEVw7ftbBbiA=
>   U2FsdGVkX1+8qW19xOpLCy1Zt5lcyxE3LIKrhs5VmjI=
>   U2FsdGVkX1/I2AuJM3jBgHuASmWQvkgmaL0RMsR2LXA=
>   U2FsdGVkX1+tR17ftLYsWGoEcRA0+zmSjkLHJE3zul0=

I think this library add random salt on my password .
How to disable this feature ?

Comment: Does the decrypt function return the same original value even if the crypted values are not equals? If so, what is the problem having different output?

Comment: I need same hash . I do something like this in Java language and always return same hash .

Comment: Even though I've provided a workaround/hack, I want to provide some `security concern` warnings . `AES` algorithm return different output for same input for a reason, Imagine you are encrypting `password` and many users are using identical password. Without the AES "ramdomness" then all identical password will have the same encrypted value. ***knowing one's password may reveal the other's***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AES` is designed to generated random output that are symmetrical (That can be decrypted)

`CryptoJS` `AES` uses `Math.random()` calls to generate a matrix/salt during cyphering and this randomness is included in the encrypted result, that's how decrypt can "uncypher" the encrypted data.

You can either ***fork the CryptoJS Library and replaces `Math.random` usage by your own seed*** or you can ***change the outcome of `Math.random` at runtime for the duration of the encryption***.

Thanks to Javascript, you can assign custom code to `native function`.

Here is Option #2. It will always return the same output, it uses the function `fakeMathRandom`. This will temporarily change the outcome of `Math.random` for the duration of the callBack function

**fakeMathRandom function**

```
function fakeMathRandom(callBack) {
     if(!callBack) throw new Error("Must provide callBack function");
     //fake predefined output setup
     let seed=0;
     const randomOutputs = [0.04,0.08,0.15,0.16,0.23,0.42,0.52,0.65,0.79,0.89];
     //save nativeFunction
     const Math_random = Math.random;
     //change nativeFunction
     Math.random = function() {return randomOutputs[seed++ % 10];}
     //runs the callback
     const callbackOutput = callBack();
     //restore nativeFunction
     Math.random = Math_random; 
     return callbackOutput;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var encrypted = fakeMathRandom(() => CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key));
```

**Complete Demo Code:**

```js
function fakeMathRandom(callBack) {
  if(!callBack) throw new Error("Must provide callBack function");
 let seed=0;
  const randomOutputs = [0.04,0.08,0.15,0.16,0.23,0.42,0.52,0.65,0.79,0.89];
  const Math_random = Math.random;
  Math.random = function() {return randomOutputs[seed++ % 10];}
  const callbackOutput = callBack();
  Math.random = Math_random;
  return callbackOutput;
}

var text = "Text to crypt!!!.";
var key  = 'secret';

var encrypted = fakeMathRandom(() => CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key)); //This will always return U2FsdGVkX18KPXCjFHrhR4Q5zBbjCf+I/m/w9jbS3EuvE59kzUxK45FrGHDpqalt
var encrypted2 = fakeMathRandom(() => CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key));
var encrypted3 = fakeMathRandom(() => CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key));

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);


document.getElementById('encrypted').innerHTML = encrypted
document.getElementById('encrypted2').innerHTML = encrypted2
document.getElementById('encrypted3').innerHTML = encrypted3
document.getElementById('decrypted').innerHTML = decrypted
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<div id="encrypted"></div>
<div id="encrypted2"></div>
<div id="encrypted3"></div>
<div id="decrypted"></div>
```

I hope that solve you problem!

Answer (score 0):

We can generate same hash like this way using CryptoJS.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let text='Rohit';
var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("27c69b41b5fe49aaa984e472d4aeaa5b");
var iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("17c69b41b5fe49aaa984e472d4aeaa5a");

var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv: iv}).toString();
console.log(ciphertext);

// Decrypt
var decryptStr  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decryptStr);
```